# Configurable logo for the template

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

I am using Fluid for developing a typo3 v8.1 template. I want to give the user the possibility to comfortable change the logo in the backend. It should be possible to change the logo for each page.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use typoscript for this.

```
lib.logo = IMG_RESOURCE
lib.logo.file = fileadmin/logo.jpg
lib.logo.file.width = 100
lib.logo.file.height = 100
lib.logo.stdWrap.wrap (
 <img src="|" alt="logo"/>
)
```

So, when the user wants to change the logo, the thing is need to do is to change lib.logo.file.

Check this code :

```
lib.logoImage = FILES
lib.logoImage {
  references {
    table = pages
    uid.data = tsfe:id
    data = levelmedia: -1, slide
    fieldName = media
  }


  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    data = file:current:publicUrl
    wrap = <img src="|" />
  }
}
```

Add logo : edit page, go to page resources tab and add logo image

Comment: How should the user change the logo for different pages?

Comment: for the different pages you can use page resources, i will get you the code for this - sorry for the late answer